# Is there a high-precision logarithm calculator in elisp?

Tags: lisp, elisp

In my class, for a final project, we are working on improving an algorithm that matches a prefix with a power of 2

(I.E. input="25", output="2^8=256",  input="99", output="2^99=9903520314283042199192993792...")

Anyways, we are relying on logarithms to identify matching prefixes. Logarithm precision actually does matter and we are looking for better log functions. The standard log function and the calc-function both have the same precision. Are there any options if I wanted even better precision?

Comment: You could try and calculate it manually.

Comment: That's actually what I'm considering.

Comment: I imagine you've checked the manual already, but as you've not mentioned it, see whether `C-h i g (calc) Precision` helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off several google searches, I've come to the conclusion that one currently does not exist. If someone where to inform me otherwise, I would happily change my best answer however.